# Calling two Html2Canvas calls using jQuery.when()

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, html2canvas

I am trying take screenshot of two divs using html2canvas. I am trying to achieve this using promises such that once both `html2canvas` calls are finished, I run my AJAX call in `then()`.

I don't know where I am going wrong. I am getting error saying:

> Uncaught TypeError: canvas.toDataURL is not a function

```js
$.when(
  html2canvas(div_elem1),
  html2canvas(div_elem2)
).then(function(canvas, canvas2) {
  myImage1 = canvas.toDataURL();
  //tried with this too, myImage1 = canvas[ 0 ].toDataURL();
  myImage = canvas2.toDataURL();
  var data = {
    action: 'save_data',
    a: $.extend({}, a),
    b: $.extend({}, b),
    base64data: {
      x: myImage,
      y: myImage1
    },
  };

  $.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {

  });
});
```

> I am using html2canvas 1.0.0-alpha.12

Edit: It works if I do this way below. But this will take a longer time comparatively

```
html2canvas(div_elem1).then(function(canvas) {

            myImage1 = canvas.toDataURL();

            html2canvas(div_elem2).then(function(canvas2) {

                    myImage = canvas2.toDataURL();

                      //ajaxcall...
```

Comment: What version of h2c are you using? [Can't repro](https://jsfiddle.net/6j5q2p8u/)

Comment: @Kaiido html2canvas 1.0.0-alpha.12

Comment: Then that's weird. Can you set up an [MCVE] please? What does `console.log(canvas, canvas2)`  outputs?

Comment: @Kaiido `console.log(canvas, canvas2)` returns `Promise {<pending>}__proto__: Promisecatch: ƒ catch()constructor: ƒ Promise()finally: ƒ finally()then: ƒ then()Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "Promise"__proto__: Object[[PromiseStatus]]: "resolved"[[PromiseValue]]: canvas Promise {<pending>}`

Comment: Maybe it something else with your code because it's working for me: https://jsbin.com/gezuruh/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: @MoshFeu Can you please see my updated question. It works that way

Comment: @Kaiido Can you please see my updated question. It works that way

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? It looks weird if it's working with one parameter but not with 2.

Comment: @MoshFeu yes it was because of the jquery version issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jquery's `.when` method in version below 3 was not compatible with Promises, only with jQuery's Deferred objects.

```js
$.when(Promise.resolve('done')).then(console.log);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You need to update your jQuery version to higher than v3 in order to be able to pass Promises to it and use your code as is.

```js
$.when(Promise.resolve('done')).then(console.log);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

But note that you don't really need to rely on jQuery here, html2canvas requires the browser to support javascript Promises, so you can very well just use the native Promise.all method:

```js
Promise.all([
  Promise.resolve('first'), // html2canvas(...),
  Promise.resolve('second') // html2canvas(...)
]).then(function(canvases) {
  var canvas = canvases[0],
    canvas_1 = canvases[1];
  console.log(canvas, canvas_1);
});
```

Comment: Yes I found that wordpress is including jquery version 1.12.4 and I think its not compatible. right ?

Comment: 1.12 oO Nope it's not. But note that you may also just use the built-in Promise.all method, will include it in my answer.